# Regular expression that matches on optional single querystring parameter

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

This IIS rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="music search state">
  <match url="^music/state/([a-zA-Z-+']+)?$"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="search.aspx?stateurl={R:1}&amp;t=2" appendQueryString="true"/>
</rule>
```

Matches on URL:
    `www.example.com/music/state/north-dakota`

But not on URL:
    `www.example.com/music/state/north-dakota?country=usa`

I also tried:

`^music/state/([a-zA-Z-+']+)?` and `^music/state/([a-zA-Z-+']+)`

But none of these work on both URLs...what do I need to change in this expression so it matches on both?

**update**

I tried extending the last part of the expression, but these 2 expressions throw a `Configuration file is not well-formed XML` error in IIS:

1. `([a-zA-Z-+'?\&=]+)`
2. `([a-zA-Z-+'?&=]+)`

and this expression does not match the URL `([a-zA-Z-+'?&amp;=]+)`

Comment: What system is this XML file written for?  You should add that tag to the question.

Comment: Do you mean you need support for the `?country=usa` part? Seems like you just need to add `?` and `=` to you regex - `^music/state/([a-zA-Z-+'=?]+)?$` for that

Comment: @Kamehameha but that would mean the countryurl value would become part of the stateurl parameter value right? That is not what I want. I should be able to add more parameters too, e.g. `www.example.com/music/state/north-dakota?country=usa&sort=az`

Comment: You might need to either remove the `$` or extend it out with a part that matches the ?country=usa part. `^music/state/([a-zA-Z+-']+)?(?:\?[&a-zA-Z+=-]*)?$` –

Comment: @sln thanks, but I tested yours and got `Configuration file is not well-formed XML`, I've updated my post with some tests I ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the regex `^music/state/([a-zA-Z-+']+)?$` part `[a-zA-Z-+']` is responsible for  all characters that can be found after `music/state/`. 
Something like this:`^music/state/([a-zA-Z-+'?&=]+)?$`

BTW, you can check you regex using online interpreter, like http://regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with this (escaping ampersand): `music/state/([a-zA-Z-+'?&amp;=]+)?$`